# How to know the boolean formula of a boolean function?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Suppose A binary boolean function is showed by a true table. How can I know the (simplest) boolean formula which is interpreted by that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer by an example...**

Given the following truth-table:

```
x | y | z | f
--|---|---|--
0 | 0 | 0 | 0
--|---|---|--
0 | 0 | 1 | 1
--|---|---|--
0 | 1 | 0 | 0
--|---|---|--
0 | 1 | 1 | 0
--|---|---|--
1 | 0 | 0 | 1
--|---|---|--
1 | 0 | 1 | 0
--|---|---|--
1 | 1 | 0 | 1
--|---|---|--
1 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

Your function is:
$f(x,y,z)=(\neg{x}\wedge\neg{y}\wedge{z})\vee({x}\wedge\neg{y}\wedge\neg{z})\vee({x}\wedge{y}\wedge\neg{z})\vee({x}\wedge{y}\wedge{z})$

If the table contains more rows with $f=1$ than rows with $f=0$, then you can apply the above technique for the rows where $f=0$ instead, and then wrap the entire expression with a $\neg(\dots)$.

Comment: How does this technique work!?

Comment: @zty: I thought that the example clarified it pretty well. For each row with $f=1$, you $\wedge$ the variables in it (using $\neg$ for variables with value $0$). Then, you $\vee$ the expressions that you've created for the rows. If the table contains more rows with $f=1$ than rows with $f=0$, then you can apply this technique for the rows where $f=0$ instead, and then wrap the entire expression with a $\neg(\dots)$.

Comment: I get it, can you explain why this technique work?

Comment: @zty: Not really. It simply translates the table into a function. So it's kind of like you're asking me to explain a translation of a word from English to German. It is just a translation, there is nothing to explain about it.

Comment: I finally get it. It's like translate boolean formula to english. How to translate the truth table to conjunctive normal form?

Comment: @zty: To a CNF? Hmmmm... that might be a little harder, I'll need to think about it (you might want to publish that as a separate question).